# Really slow Job creation and initialization using Unity's Job System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parallel-processing, unity-container, jobs

Why is the initialization of Job Structs in the Unity Job System taking so long? Using the code below, I'm getting ~2 ms per Update to declare and initialize 20 `TestJob` structs. May not seem like a lot of time but when you think about everything else that needs to be done and the effect that has on FPS, it adds up.

I tested just a regular struct with normal Lists and Arrays and it is 100x faster. What is going on here? Am I doing something wrong or do NativeContainers just take an insane amount of time to initialize?

```
void Update()
{
    JobInitializationTesting();
}

public void JobInitializationTesting()
{
    float totalTime = 0;
    int loops = 20;

    NativeList<JobHandle> jobHandleList = new NativeList<JobHandle>(Allocator.Temp);
    List<TestJob> jobList = new List<TestJob>();

    for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
    {
        float startTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;

        TestJob testJob = new TestJob()
        {
            testInt = i,
            testArray = new NativeArray<int>(10, Allocator.TempJob),
            testArrayTwo = new NativeArray<int>(10, Allocator.TempJob),

            testList = new NativeList<float3>(Allocator.TempJob),
            testListTwo = new NativeList<float3>(Allocator.TempJob),
            testListInt = new NativeList<int>(Allocator.TempJob)
        };

        totalTime += Time.realtimeSinceStartup - startTime;

        jobHandleList.Add(testJob.Schedule());
        jobList.Add(testJob);
    }

    //  Print the total time it took to initialize all jobs to the console
    Debug.Log((totalTime * 1000f) + " ms");

    JobHandle.CompleteAll(jobHandleList);

    for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
    {
        jobList[i].testArray.Dispose();
        jobList[i].testArrayTwo.Dispose();
        jobList[i].testList.Dispose();
        jobList[i].testListTwo.Dispose();
        jobList[i].testListInt.Dispose();
    }
}
```

```
public struct TestJob : IJob
{
    public int testInt;
    public NativeArray<int> testArray;
    public NativeArray<int> testArrayTwo;
    public NativeList<float3> testList;
    public NativeList<float3> testListTwo;
    public NativeList<int> testListInt;

    public void Execute()
    {
        testInt += 1;
        testArray[0] = testInt;
    }
}
```

Comment: The time is based on the what is being done in the constructor and the amount of memory being used.  I would do some benchmarking to determine why it is so slow.

Comment: @jdweng Suggestions on what kind of benchmarking to do? I've completely isolated it. Not sure how else to test this..

Answer (score 0):

Old post but I saw something that could contribute to, if not cause, the slowdown you're seeing. Let me hopefully clarify a few things for future reference by anyone who, like me, stumbles upon this thread in the distant future.

**The likely problem is unnecessary sanitization**. The `NativeArray` constructor, when using the overload that takes an `int` and an `Allocator`, has a third, optional argument. This argument specifies whether Unity should set the bytes in the block of native memory to zero. If you're only writing to a `NativeArray`, or if you're initializing every element of the `NativeArray` with a value other than the default of the element type, or if, for every index of the NativeArray, you can guarantee that the index is never read from before being written to at least once (think of an array-backed list for example), then tell Unity that it needn't clean memory.

As far as I've been able to tell by looking at publicly available source code, internally the NativeArray constructor uses a memclear function to set all bytes to zero, which is fast, but if the whole operation is pointless then it's just a big sink of CPU cycles. Wherever possible, use `NativeArrayOptions.UninitializedMemory`.

I also saw a few inefficiencies in the handling of Jobs in your experiment. Granted, your experiment wasn't on using Jobs but the speed of `NativeArray` initialization but I'll point out the three inefficiencies I see for the record.

**Optimization 1**: don't instant-wait. You create the job and await it within the same `Update()` call. This is very slow. If you check in the Unity Profiler you will see why: Unity is actually running them on the main thread instead of in a job thread. I'm not sure why, but I presume it's the scheduler's fault. There's a brief delay between scheduling the job and it actually running.

By the time you demand the job be completed, no Job thread has yet picked up the scheduled work, so because the main thread says that it needs a result pronto, the main thread ends up doing the work. This means that the result is identical to your base case, where you're using regular arrays and lists and not using jobs, except with the slight overhead of the job system.

The solution is to give Unity some time to work, typically by having the main thread do something else to keep it occupied while the Job threads do their, well, job. Something that worked for me is to schedule dependent Jobs in `Update` and then await the result in `LateUpdate`. That means that Unity continues executing the remainder of the `MonoBehaviour.Update()` calls in the scene, while Job threads process through the scheduled work. By the time `LateUpdate()` comes around, the work is likely already done, meaning that the wait is negligible. This in turn completely negates the overhead of the Job system scheduler.

**Optimization 2**: mark Job members. If an array is only written to or only read from, use the C# `readonly` keyword, and the Unity-provided attributes `ReadOnly` and `WriteOnly`. This helps scheduling by explicitly ensuring the lack of read-after-write race conditions. The bulk of the benefit though is for the Burst compiler. Speaking of which:

**Optimization 3**: Burst-compile jobs. This one is a little sneaky, but for maximal Job performance, you need to mark your Job structs with the `Unity.Burst.BurstCompile` attribute. If you have the Burst package installed (which I suspect you do, since you are using data types defined in Unity.Mathematics, which is a dependency of Burst) then adding `BurstCompile` will mean that, on the first schedule, the job runs as normal. However, this also causes the Burst compiler to start asynchronously compiling the Job into highly optimized native code. **The sheer ludicrousness of the speedup that Burst can provide cannot be overstated.** Burst is also where most of the magic of the Unity.Mathematics package comes into play, since Burst compiles the code in this package into highly optimized, SIMD-accelerated CPU instructions. In my test case, a Job went from taking 7 ms, to about 0.5 ms, just by letting Burst handle it.